# Ipad UIImagePickerController and UIPopoverController error

Tags: ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I am using this code to open a popover with imagepicker

```
-(IBAction)photosAction:(id)sender 
{
// dismiss any left over popovers here
UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; 
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary; 
picker.delegate = self; 

UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
self.popoverController = popover;          
popoverController.delegate = self;
[popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

But this results in this error **request for member 'popoverController' in something not a structure or union** and this error **'popoverController' undeclared (first use in this function)**.

Also I want to dismiss the popover when the image is selected.

What code should I put in the following function to dismiss the popover once the image is selected.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error was caused becaused my function requires a bar button item and i was using a normal ui button.

Comment: I've been pounding my head on the same problem.  Any chance you could post your code?  Did you change the UI to use a bar button item, or change the code?

Answer (score 7):

The error means popoverController hasn't been declared in the view controller.  You need to add it to the interface as an ivar and property (it's not built-in):

```
@interface ... {
     ...
     UIPopoverController *popoverController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *popoverController;
@end
```

In the implementation, add the @synthesize, set it to nil in viewDidUnload, and release in dealloc.

To dismiss the popover, you would call [dismissPopoverAnimated:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPopoverController/dismissPopoverAnimated:).

```
[self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the errors. But when I click on the button which is supposed to load the popover I get these errors in Console. 

*** -[UIRoundedRectButton view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d1e140

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[UIRoundedRectButton view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d1e140

Comment: What action have you set for the button click?  Show the code that creates the button.  Make sure selector in addTarget says "photosAction:" with colon at end.  Of if button is created in IB, check the connection for touch-up-inside.

Comment: IBOutlet UIButton * selectImageBtn;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton * selectImageBtn;
@synthesize selectImageBtn

Comment: Now, when I put this code it works.

UIPopoverController* aPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
    [aPopover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 320)];
    
    [aPopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(200,200,-100,-100) inView:self.view  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
 self.popoverController1 = aPopover;

Comment: Not so sure whether it's a good idea to retain the popoverController. I guess the popoverController is also retaining the contentsViewController and probably releasing it in it's dealloc, which will cause them never to release each other.

Answer (score 0):

try using this code :

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 400.0, 400.0) 
                         inView:self.view
       permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                       animated:YES];
```