# UIPopoverController placement

Tags: ios, ipad, orientation, uipopovercontroller

I'm working on an app that is supposed to be universal, one app for both iPad and iPhone.  I would like to keep their interfaces as similar as possible.  In the iPhone app I am using a Tab bar controller, and one of those tabs goes to an image picker controller.   Obviously I cannot do that in iPad.  So I have hijacked control of that button to bring a popupcontroller that has the image picker in it.  This all works well enough, except when I bring up the popup, it is not in the correct place.  When I rotate the simulator, the popup goes to the correct place, and stays when I rotate back even.

My code is based on the code in this question:
[Ipad UIImagePickerController and UIPopoverController error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818919/ipad-uiimagepickercontroller-and-uipopovercontroller-error)

Why would my popup not be in the correct location?

Comment: Does the popover initially show up in the correct spot if you hold it in a particular (landscape / portrait) orientation, or is it always off?  Also, are you applying any transforms to the view the popover is being shown for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code is based on the question you referenced, it would appear you are using the following code to show the popover:

```
[popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender
                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp 
                                          animated:YES]
```

UIPopoverController:presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:permittedArrowDirections:animated accepts a UIBarButtonItem* for the sender which your UITabBar does not have.  UITabBar uses UITabBarItem which has a base of UIBarItem.  UIBarButtonItem also has that base (UIBarItem).

Anyhow...  I also needed to show a uipopovercontroller from a tabbaritem, I used the following code:

```
MyViewController *myVC = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:myVC];
[myVC release];
popover.popoverContentSize = myVC.view.frame.size;
popover.delegate = self;
int tabBarItemWidth = self.tabBar.frame.size.width / [self.tabBar.items count];
int x = tabBarItemWidth * 6;
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(x, 0, tabBarItemWidth, self.tabBar.frame.size.height);
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:rect
                         inView:self.tabBar 
       permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp 
                       animated:YES];
```

Note:  your x calculation will be different.  The tab bar item selected for me was the 6th one.
Basically

```
x = tabBarItemWidth * currentTabBarItemIndex;
```

Comment: forgot to mention this link [how-can-i-have-a-popover-come-from-a-tab-instead-of-a-view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405350/how-can-i-have-a-popover-come-from-a-tab-instead-of-a-view).  Its similar to the answer / code I gave you, but I like my solution more since the popover in mine appears directly under the tabbaritem that was selected.

Comment: Did this resolve your problem?  I'm pretty sure calling the UIPopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem is not supported for UITabBarItems.  When you compile, does it generate a warning?

Comment: I get no warnings from it, because I'm actually sending it an ID that I hooked up to the tab button in IB