# PopOver in a UItabBar

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitabbar, uipopover

I need to create a popover in a tabBar in the right side of it.

Like the:

```
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
```

property in a navigationBar.

[image]

(Forget the other buttons, i just need one button.)
Any idea of how doing this??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a popover to appear over a tabbaritem you could look at my answer here: [UIPopoverController placement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278236/uipopovercontroller-placement)

Comment: But how can i add that button in the tab bar, to be in right side of the TabBar??

Comment: This may not be the most elegant solution, but I also needed to do that for my project, so I just created two tab bars.  The first was to get the tab bar look across the device, the second was to place the tab bar buttons on the right.  The second tab bar was not as wide (since uitabbar will center uitabbaritems by default) and the second was placed on the right.

Comment: I added mine in the xib of my view controller.  You will not be able to resize the height, but you can change the width.  Just change the frame of the UITabBar.  like, myTabBar.frame = CGRectMake(x,myTabBar.frame.origin.y,100,myTabBar.frame.size.height);  Set the x such that it appears on the right side.

Comment: i had soved my problem... just create a uibutton, calculate the position where i wanted the button, a